# Html to Agular2 how to make drop downs working.

Tags: angular

I have html which i need to convert in angular2 but as no jquery working there could any one suggest how to make it working. The below dropdown :

```html
<section class="searchBlock">
<!-- index page -->
        <div class="searchSection">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Service made easy</h2>
                    <div class="selectbar">
                        <div class="inputBar">
                            <input placeholder="Search Business">
                        </div>
                        <div class="selectBar">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn_date btn-default dropdown-toggle text-left" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                San Francisco, CA
                                </button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="date_field">
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu fight-check-boxes date-listing" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li data-id="1" data-value="">
                                    San Francisco, CA1
                                </li>
                                <li data-id="2" data-value="">
                                    San Francisco, CA2
                                </li>
                                <li data-id="3" data-value="">
                                    San Francisco, CA3
                                </li>
                                <li data-id="4" data-value="">
                                    San Francisco, CA4
                                </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="searchBtn">
                            <button><span></span> Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    <!-- index page -->
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
          
            $(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
             $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn_date').html($(this).text());
             $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn_date').val($(this).data('value'));
             var data_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
               $(this).parent().siblings("input[type='hidden']").val(data_id);
            });
         });
      </script>
```

the above snippet contains drop down in html i need to make it working in angular2

Comment: what do you mean by that it's not working exactly?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
          
            $(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
             $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn_date').html($(this).text());
             $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn_date').val($(this).data('value'));
             var data_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
               $(this).parent().siblings("input[type='hidden']").val(data_id);
            });
         });


Actually i need to convert html template to angular2 and I mean to say this jquery is not working in angular2

Comment: So what's this supposed to do. I know nothing of jquery :D And what have you tried to make it like *Angularish*? Could you create a plunker showcasing the issue you are facing? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn_date btn-default dropdown-toggle text-left" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" (click)="toggleDropdown()" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    San Francisco, CA
  </button>
  <input type="hidden" name="date_field">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu fight-check-boxes date-listing" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" *ngIf="dropdown">
    <li data-id="1" data-value="">
      San Francisco, CA1
    </li>
    <li data-id="2" data-value="">
      San Francisco, CA2
    </li>
    <li data-id="3" data-value="">
      San Francisco, CA3
    </li>
    <li data-id="4" data-value="">
      San Francisco, CA4
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And in your .ts file:

```
public dropdown: boolean = false;

public toggleDropdown() {
   this.dropdown = !this.dropdown
}
```

Your ul tag will show/hide depence on dropdown variable

Comment: @Wesley Coetzee oh sorry

Comment: @FierceDev hey thanks for the code but it didn't work